# The set of perfect sets has cardinality $2^{\aleph_{0}}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

We say that $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is *perfect* if it is closed and contains no isolated points. The claim is that

> $| \{ P \subseteq \mathbb{R} \mid P \text{ is perfect} \} | =
> 2^{\aleph_{0}}$.

The idea is to build an injection from $\{ P \subseteq \mathbb{R} \mid P \text{ is perfect} \} $ onto $\mathbb{R}$ and then an injection from $\mathbb{R}$ onto $\{ P \subseteq \mathbb{R} \mid P \text{ is perfect} \}$ and then invoke the Schroder-Bernstein Theorem.

I believe that I have found an injection from $\{ P \subseteq \mathbb{R} \mid P \text{ is perfect} \} $ onto $\mathbb{R}$, but the other direction is what is giving me trouble. In the text I am working from, the hint said that finding an injection from $\{ P \subseteq \mathbb{R} \mid P \text{ is perfect} \} $ onto $\mathbb{R}$ should be reasonably straight forward. However the only way that seems immediately apparent to me to build an injection is to use the Axiom of Choice and transfinite recursion to associate to each perfect set with a real number such that no real number represents the same perfect set, which can be accomplished as I have already shown that each perfect set is uncountable.

Comment: I suppose that I would not consider using the Axiom of Choice and transfinite recursion as ''straight forward'' and maybe that is what I am getting hung up on.

Comment: Little sideremark: "onto" is widely used as synonym for "surjective"; "into" is the neutral term

Comment: I would think the injection $f:\Bbb R\to \{P\mid P\text{ is perfect} \}$ given by $f(x)=[x-1,x]$ is the straight-forward one.

Comment: @Arthur Ahhh yes, all closed intervals are perfect and this is clearly injective. This was tremendously helpful.

Comment: Interestingly, as much as I post about the cardinality of the collections of closed sets, Borel sets, etc. I don't recall off-hand how one normally does this for the collection of perfect sets (which is the first step to those other results). But one thing that occurred to me is that you can show there are $2^{{\aleph}_0}$ many arrangements for countably many open intervals on the real line.

Comment: @Dave: It seems to me that the easiest way to get the upper bound is to note that there are at most $2^\omega$ closed sets. This in turn follows from the fact that since $\Bbb R$ is second countable, there are at most $2^\omega$ open sets.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: Yes, I remember this method now. Given how much I've posted online since 1999, I wouldn't be surprised if I gave this argument somewhere. Anyway, if anyone is interested, the argument I was thinking of is that the complement of a perfect set (or any closed set for that matter) can be written as the union of at most countably many maximal open intervals, and the number of such at most countable collections of open intervals is no more than the number of at most $\omega$-length sequences of open intervals, which winds up being $c$ since there are $c$ many open intervals.